# GridLayout exceeds its size

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout

I created `JPanel` and set the layout to `GridLayout`, I set it to have 3 rows and 5 columns.
But when i added 11 JButtons to this panel it show 3 rows and 4 columns each row.
I want the JButtons to be displayed in 3 row with 5 columns.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 5));
        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
            JButton jButton = new JButton("Click");
            panel.add(jButton);
        }
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(false);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: It's a pity you did not heed my advice to post an MRE / SSCCE. There **is** a solution to this problem.

Comment: *I'm looking for a more effective way to fix it without adding unnecessary objects* - yes there is a way to fix this without adding unnecessary objects. but you still haven't posted your [mre] demonstrating the problem so we can't show you what to change. Every question should have an MRE so we know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I have added a minimal example.

Comment: `frame.setLocationByPlatform(false);` Aside: That is the default value, but I prefer enabling it (`setLocationByPlatform(true)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seen for 11 objects added.

`new GridLayout(3, 5)`

[image]

But now look at the result of *replacing the first parameter with 0.*

`new GridLayout(0, 5)`

[image]

The trick to this is described in the **Parameters** section of [the constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/GridLayout.html#%3Cinit%3E(int,int)).

> **Parameters**
>
> `rows` - the rows, with the value **zero meaning any number of rows**.
>
> `cols` - the columns, with the value **zero meaning any number of columns**.

The same thing happens with the 4 parameter version of the `GridLayout` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to add some kind of fillers for the rest slots of the grid layout. A grid layout of 3 rows and 5 columns can take 3x5 = 15 components. Since you add 11 components, there are 4 slots/positions empty. Using fillers on these positions will give you the result you want.

See my example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 5));
        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
            JLabel label = new JLabel("something");
            label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.green));
            panel.add(label);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 3 * 5 - panel.getComponentCount(); i++) {
            panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension()));
        }
        frame.add(panel);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    });
}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks it works but I'll wait for more answers, I'm looking for a more effective way to fix it without adding unnecessary objects

Comment: @matan When it comes to `GridLayout`, I do not think there is a more "effective way" to do it. Also, this is a common practice to use in `GridLayout`. Another way would be a `GridBagLayout`.

Comment: @GeorgeZ. *"I do not think there is a more "effective way" to do it."* Sure there is. See my answer for details. Your approach is not a bad way to reproduce the effect, but in this instance, there are easier ways to achieve it.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Right. I wish the "more effective way" was defined. Anyway +1 to your answer. To be honest, i did not spend more time trying to find a solution that does not require fillers. I took granted that if you ask 3 rows in constructor, you want 3 rows for future component additions. But as it seems, the 11 components is the final number of components.

Comment: *"I wish the "more effective way" was defined."* Well it 'is', but I think it might ideally be made more clear in the docs. Even the section made **bold** in my answer does not immediately jump out to me as the solution. It was more a case of knowing how it works through experience, then looking in the docs for the explanation. Maybe it is further elaborated in the tutorial but.. *"i did not spend more time trying to find a solution that does not require fillers"* yeah .. likewise I could not be bothered checking the tutorial. Meh. We all have to decide how to allocate our 'time resources'. ;)